# Update statement to change timestamp field add year to current values

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to be able to update a specific column in a table that is a time stamp. Its an expirationdate column and I need to add 5 years to the values in that. For these specific ids that are set to expire at some future date.Could anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

I *presume* that expiration **date** doesn't actually contain fractional seconds; that's most probably truncated to *day*, so date datatype is `date`. If that's so, then `add_months` is one option: 5 (years) * 12 (months) = 60 monts:

```
SQL> create table test as
  2    select sysdate as expiration_date from dual;

Table created.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select expiration_date,
  2    add_months(expiration_date, 12 * 5) new_value
  3  from test;

EXPIRATION_DATE     NEW_VALUE
------------------- -------------------
06.04.2022 21:28:13 06.04.2027 21:28:13

SQL>
```

---

In order to *update* current values, you'd

```
update test set
  expiration_date = add_months(expiration_date, 12 * 5)
where ...
```

Comment: Would that query generate a new column?

Comment: @RyanWills It would **display** a new column in the result set of the query but it would not **create** a new column in the table.

Comment: You don't want to create a new column, do you? You'd just update current value - have a look at edited answer which shows *how*.